# DAX - is it efficient to use CALCULATE inside SUMX?

Tags: dax, daxstudio

Is it efficient in term of performance this measure:

```
MyCoeff :=
SUMX (
    Articles,
        CALCULATE (
            DIVIDE ( [Sales Net Amt AY], [Sales Qty AY], 0 ) * [Sales Qty LY]
        )
)
```

Comment: How many rows The Article table has? Is it necessary to iterate the full table?

Comment: it depends on rows qty. I quess that Articles is a small table, so it's ok and may be a good solution. Of course it's very individual. You can create several measures and check speep at DAX Studio

Comment: if [Sales Net Amt AY], [Sales Qty AY] are measures then you dont need Calcukate, DAX will add for enclosed measure.